# VSCode setting 'insertFinalNewline' not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

From other posts I've read setting this to true should work. I have it set this way for both User and Workspace settings, however, whenever I save a file e.g. app.js, it removes and/or doesn't add the newline.

```
{
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the same issue were caused by `lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter` plugin. Disabled it - and problem disappeared.

Comment: My issue was the same

Answer (score 0):

After disabling all plugins except for newline it resolved the issue. I am working back through activating each to see what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Editorconfig extension installed? A bunch of people reported that it's causing this issue. It's being tracked here: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode/issues/169